# RESTFULL angular generate mpdf and force download

Tags: angularjs, rest, mpdf, generated

I have a little problem here.
I'm using angular, and restfull application. My goal is, when I click on a button I force download a pdf which has been generated on the fly, and not stocked.

So I use mpdf :

```
ob_start();
include PATH_VIEWS_PDF . "pdf/template.view.php";
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(85.60, 53.98),'','',0,0,0,0,0,0);
$mpdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$mpdf->SetTitle($title);
$mpdf->SetAuthor("author");
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(ob_get_clean(), 2);
$mpdf->Output(file.pdf,"D");
```

But the response I have is always in binary format like this in the console (using firebug):

> %PDF-1.4
>   %����
>   3 0 obj
>   <
>   /Parent 1 0 R
>   /MediaBox [0 0 242.646 153.014]
>   /TrimBox [0.000 0.000 242.646 153.014]
>   /Resources 2 0 R
>   /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
>   /Contents 4 0 R>>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   x��W�n#7�Y_����m��^�u���
>   �`���....
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   1 0 obj

etc....
I also added

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/pdf';
```

in my angular request but it does nothing.
I know that without angular and restfull mecanism, (classic php call from html page with url) it works but with angular and restfull, it does not work, I have this binary thing in console instead.

It seems to me that it's a header problem, but normally, mpdf take care of that.

Any ideas ?

thx a lot